# Find out which Akka version is used by Play

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, akka, akka-testkit

I need to add dependency on `akka-testkit` to my Play! application. I would like to avoid hardcoding the version of Akka and stick to the one used by Play instead (to ensure compatibility).

```
"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-testkit" % akkaVersion % Test
```

Is it possible to obtain the version in my `build.sbt`? The only place where I see it listed is in Play's [`project/Dependencies.scala`](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/ba894f661ec6392415fcafdf44cc18edde34f1ef/framework/project/Dependencies.scala#L112).

Comment: You can simplify make the build save the dependency version in some resource file (or generated source) included at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You can do 'show full-classpath' on sbt command line to see what akka its picking up.

Or even better you can use [sbt dependency graph](https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph) to get a more detailed view

Comment: The problem is not how to determine the version manually, but how to do it automatically during the build. So, e.g. it would be updated to the proper version when upgrading Play!

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced the same issue and solved it by defining akka-toolkit dependency as following (`build.sbt`):

```
"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-testkit" % play.core.PlayVersion.akkaVersion % "test"
```

I also have Play added via sbt plugin (`project/plugins.sbt`):

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.8.20")
```

For readability, you can extract `play.core.PlayVersion.akkaVersion` to a variable and/or use imports to not be forced to type the full path